# Object doesn't exist in DB after consequential api calls

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-orm

I have the following flow for object creation:
A user wants to create an object on a webservice. In order to do it - I check if the user is eligible to pay a fee for it.

1. We make a request to know how much the user should pay. If 0 - user will see the regular Create button, if >0 he will see the PayPal button.
2. User fills in data and in the second case presses the PayPal button.
3. We make 2 consequential API requests:

1. Create an object with the parameter is_draft=True. Return its id.
2. Create an order object and use the id from the previous step.

4. Sometimes we cannot create an order, because the object doesn't exist in DB yet.

Django setting:

`DATABASES["default"]["ATOMIC_REQUESTS"] = True`

Django models:

```
class Object1(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()
   ...

class Object2(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()
   ...

class Order(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)
   amount = models.DecimalField()

   #naive polymorphism
   object1 = models.ForeignKey(Object1)
   object2 = models.ForeignKey(Object2)

# An object will be created after PayPal's call to the webhook endpoint
class OrderPayment(models.Model):
   ...
   order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
```

The problem is that when I try to create an order to want to assign object1 or object2 as FK it doesn't exist yet. Also I cannot call `transaction.commit()` after any object creation (Object1 or Object2) because I use atomic request and it leads to an error:

```
django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: This is forbidden when an 'atomic' block is active.
```

How can I ensure objects existence in DB?

**:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::UPDATE:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::**

I am sorry, I gave a lot of irrelevant info.
Basically the flow is:

1. Make an API request to create an Object1. Return its id.
   Behind the the API is simple CreateAPIView from DRF.
2. Make an API request to create an Order with the ID from previous step.

In the second step, I try to create an object and create a relation with Object1 which might not exist sometimes.

UPDATE2

views.py

```
class CreateObject1APIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer = Object1Serializer

class CreateOrderAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer = OrderSerializer

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        # Everything fails after calling save method, as Object1 sometimes doesn't exist.
        serializer.save()

        OrderService.call()
```

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {"default": env.db("DATABASE_URL")}
DATABASES["default"]["ATOMIC_REQUESTS"] = True
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is helpful for this scenario but i think you can use the `exists()` function like this `Model.objects.filter(pk=pk).exists()`

Comment: @Dad Sorry, didn't mention that issue is based on a fact that Object1 or Object2 doesn't exist when I want to create an Order object with FK to Object1 or Object2.

Comment: 1. Show the code logic. 2. You are not supposed to commit explicitly when using `ATOMIC_REQUESTS`.

Comment: @aaron added an Update section

Comment: @aaron Added API endpoints

Comment: Is Object1 ALWAYS supposed to exist? Is this a problem with Object1 being created successfully, and just not picking that up correctly and trying to send a null object1 field to Order?

Comment: @Trent Order object can be created with either Object1 or Object2. Anyway, the main problem is that sometimes I want to assign FK to a nonexistent object in DB. I guess I can fix it by `if Object1.objects.filter(id=<id>).exitst(): ...    else: sleep(5)`, but it doesn't look good